# chrome extension for YouTube video playback

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, html5-video

I wrote an extension for YouTube which among other things, pauses YouTube's video play back when page is opened. The problem is the video pauses but the video tool bar is not updating so it shows the pause button instead of the play button.

this is my code:

```
html5Videos = document.querySelectorAll("video");
    for (var v = 0; v < html5Videos.length; v++)
        html5Videos[v].pause();
```

I can't find a way to update the video tool bar.

[This is how it looks, I need to hit play but the pause button is shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGmyk.jpg)

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the `pause` button element and `click` it:

```js
document.querySelector('.ytp-play-button').click();
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem.